# "TimeoutException" error is triggered when .click action is triggered

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium web automation with python and I am trying to automate a login page action.
Entering username and password works fine, but when reaching the click action to submit them , the following error is triggered:

```
 self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']").click()
```

test_xxxManagement.py:27:

---

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:80: in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:633: in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:321: in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)

---

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7f8e595c76a0>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"timeout","message":"","stacktrace":"WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/co...1:5\nTimeoutError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:450:5\nbail@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:220:19\n"}}'}

```
def check_response(self, response):
    """
    Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.

    :Args:
     - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
       object.

    :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
    """
    status = response.get('status', None)
    if status is None or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
        return
    value = None
    message = response.get("message", "")
    screen = response.get("screen", "")
    stacktrace = None
    if isinstance(status, int):
        value_json = response.get('value', None)
        if value_json and isinstance(value_json, basestring):
            import json
            try:
                value = json.loads(value_json)
                if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                    value = value['value']
                status = value.get('error', None)
                if status is None:
                    status = value["status"]
                    message = value["value"]
                    if not isinstance(message, basestring):
                        value = message
                        message = message.get('message')
                else:
                    message = value.get('message', None)
            except ValueError:
                pass

    exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
    if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
        exception_class = NoSuchElementException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
        exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
        exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
    elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
        exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
        exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR \
            or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR \
            or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER:
        exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotInteractableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
        exception_class = InvalidCookieDomainException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
        exception_class = UnableToSetCookieException
    elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
        exception_class = TimeoutException
    elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
        exception_class = TimeoutException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        exception_class = WebDriverException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
        exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
        exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
        exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
        exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
        exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
    elif status in ErrorCode.JAVASCRIPT_ERROR:
        exception_class = JavascriptException
    elif status in ErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_CREATED:
        exception_class = SessionNotCreatedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT:
        exception_class = InvalidArgumentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_COOKIE:
        exception_class = NoSuchCookieException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN:
        exception_class = ScreenshotException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED:
        exception_class = ElementClickInterceptedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INSECURE_CERTIFICATE:
        exception_class = InsecureCertificateException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COORDINATES:
        exception_class = InvalidCoordinatesException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID:
        exception_class = InvalidSessionIdException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_METHOD:
        exception_class = UnknownMethodException
    else:
        exception_class = WebDriverException
    if value == '' or value is None:
        value = response['value']
    if isinstance(value, basestring):
        if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, value)
        raise exception_class(value)
    if message == "" and 'message' in value:
        message = value['message']

    screen = None
    if 'screen' in value:
        screen = value['screen']

    stacktrace = None
    if 'stackTrace' in value and value['stackTrace']:
        stacktrace = []
        try:
            for frame in value['stackTrace']:
                line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymous>')
                if line:
                    file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonymous>')
                if 'className' in frame:
                    meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                msg = msg % (meth, file)
                stacktrace.append(msg)
        except TypeError:
            pass
    if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
        raise exception_class(response, message)
    elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
        alert_text = None
        if 'data' in value:
            alert_text = value['data'].get('text')
        elif 'alert' in value:
            alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
```

> ```
>   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> ```

E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242: TimeoutException

This is the piece of code executed:
def test_Login(self):

```
    Email = self.driver.find_element_by_id("session_email")
    Email.send_keys("<email>")

    Password = self.driver.find_element_by_id("session_password")
    Password.send_keys("<password>")

    Login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
```

Login_button.click()
## Code triggers the error after the click action

```
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, "pageTitle"))

I tried to execute the code on both Chrome and Firefox, but wiith the same results.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please add the line of html which contains the element you are trying to click in the question? One possible reason could be that the button is hidden, .i.e, it has the property `style="display: hidden;"` which prevents selenium from detecting it.

If that is the case, then try the snippet below

```
button_element= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
#This makes the button clickable
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display='block'",button_element)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']").click()
```

Another issue could be that the button is getting obscured or just doesn't work with selenium, for that you can try clicking it via JS:

```
#The js click command doesn't care if the button is being obscured by a div element and just force-clicks it.
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_element)
```

Comment: This would be the html element I try to click on: <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" type="submit" value="Login" xpath="1">

Comment: The html script does not contain this property "style="display: hidden;""
 However, it worked by clicking it via JS. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome and I am glad that it worked via JS. Can you please select the answer as correct answer since it met your requirements? Thanks.